# Immediately catch keyboard entry in C without hitting ENTER

Tags: c, validation, io

I was wondering if it was possible to write an input loop in C where I do not need to hit ENTER key to send input for processing : as soon as input is entered, the system catches the keyboard entry. Please how can I achieve this?

The reasoning behind this is I am trying to code a finite state machine that receives a sequence of integer inputs and validates these inputs in an order and if a wrong input is entered, it cries out that an error has occurred, and these input are validated till the last expected digit is entered. Please help

Comment: You can use what a keylogger uses. Reading from the device itself directly. But that's a little to complicated for normal projects.

Comment: The comp.lang.c FAQ has also something to say about this.